# Subject: Is "it" mandatory in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have following construction. I have been told it is not grammatical.

> But now, another problem might arise due to unknown unavailable
>   edges, i.e. A-B and C-D and should be avoided.

I am not quite sure what the error is. But I guess, in the second sentence "it" is missing.

so, if I write like this, would it be OK?

> But now, another problem might arise due to unknown unavailable
>   edges, i.e. A-B and C-D, so that it should be avoided.

Please tell me how it should be, then I can think and learn.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the problem or the unavailable edges? I can't tell in this context. It would be a difference of using "it" or "they". Or you could specify it in the last clause to make it clear.

Comment: @user3169 The *and* requires that the parsing is *problem ... should be avoided* because *and* coordinates, and *should* can only be coordinated with the other finite verb in the sentence: *might*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather write the sentence as follows:

> But now another problem might arise due to unknown unavailable edges, i.e. A-B and C-D, and should be avoided.

"And should be avoided" is referred to "another problem." You could also write the sentence as follows, but the sentence I wrote before would be understood too.

> But now another problem might arise due to unknown unavailable edges, i.e. A-B and C-D, and it should be avoided.

Instead of introducing the parenthetical with commas, you can use parenthesis.

> But now another problem might arise due to unknown unavailable edges (i.e. A-B and C-D) and it should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

The punctuation is wonky, and the sentence could be made a little clearer, but it is not "ungrammatical". Here are some possibilities:

> But another problem might now arise (due to edges A-B and C-D being unknown and/or unavailable) and should be avoided.
>
> Another problem, which should be avoided, will arise if edges A-B and C-D are unknown and/or unavailable.
>
> If edges A-B and C-D are unknown and/or unavailable, another problem may now arise and should be avoided.
>
> Edges A-B and C-D being unknown and/or unavailable may now give rise to another problem, which should be avoided.